# Where is "PTBatcher" in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, image-processing, batch, panorama

I used PTBatcher (from package hugin) in a script on Ubuntu 14 LTS to create panoramas photos.

I switched to 16.04 and now this tools does not exist any more.

I used it like this:

```
PTBatcher -a foo.pto -o out.tif
PTBatcher -b
```

How to do this on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 4):

It seems, You can't get `PTBatcher` command line tool anymore. That tool is [declared obsolete](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/releases/2014.0.0/en.shtml) and removed since version 2014. See the [release note for version 2014 here](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/releases/2014.0.0/en.shtml) However, some new command line alternatives have been added. Those are `pto_mask`, `pto_template`, `pto_move` etc.

You can use `PTBatcherGUI` tool instead. It has [BatchProcessing](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_FAQ#Batch_processing) support.

You can get that installing `hugin`. Do it in a terminal with the command

```
sudo apt install hugin
```

But the package in Ubuntu repository for Xenial is old (version 2015). You can get a more recent version by using [`hugin/hugin-builds` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hugin/+archive/ubuntu/hugin-builds). From PPA description page, the builds are fairly stable.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hugin/hugin-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hugin
```

You can also use some of the techniques described in these pages for command line processing

- [Panotools Wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/index.php?title=Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell&oldid=15700)
- [Hugin Batch Processing](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_FAQ#Batch_processing)

Comment: It looks like the `hugin` package in the 16.04 repositories includes `PTBatcherGUI`, but not the command-line `PTBatcher`. Do you know if the `hugin` package in the PPA includes the `PTBatcher` tool?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Yes. it seems that tool is declared obsolete and removed since version 2014

Comment: Huh. I wonder if there's an alternate way for @guettli to accomplish their task. Maybe PTBatcher's functionality was rolled into the main `hugin` command???

Comment: @NickWeinberg yes. `PTBatcherGUI` was supposed to be the alternative. And I found a helpful page with lots of command line options. http://wiki.panotools.org/index.php?title=Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell&oldid=15700

Comment: Oh cool! Good work, detective!

Comment: Thanks @NickWeinberg. I was forced to discover this fact, otherwise my answer would be wrong :). Again thanks for that feedback.